# trajectories in ListPlot[the maximal prime factor of average of twin prime pair]

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers

[another sequence on twin primes](http://my.unix-center.net/~martian/math%20album/%E6%95%B0%E5%AD%A6%E4%B8%93%E8%BE%91%202%20-%20%E5%86%B0%E5%B2%9B%E7%81%AB%E5%B1%B1/%E7%9B%B4%E5%B8%83%E7%BD%97%E9%99%80%E7%9A%84%E5%B7%A8%E5%B2%A9%20(On%20twin%20prime).html) The maximal prime factor of average of twin prime pair:

n = 100000;
averageList = Select[Prime[Range[n]], PrimeQ[# + 2] &] + 1;
mpfList = FactorInteger[#][[-1, 1]] & /@ averageList;
ListPlot[%]

Why does this diagram look like a series of trajectories? 
[image]

Comment: Slightly neater: `With[{n = 10^5}, ListPlot[Composition[First, Last, FactorInteger] /@ (1 + Select[Prime[Range[n]], PrimeQ[# + 2] &])]];`

Comment: Could you show us this plot for small n (say n<100)? It would help me to be sure of my interpretation of your code, as I'm not as fluent in Mathematica as I used to be. Thanks.

Comment: Never mind about the plot, if my answer below is sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nth twin prime pair appears to be around $c n \log^2 n$ for a constant $c$, large $n$.  The largest prime factor of any non-prime $m$ is equal to $n/m'$ where $m'\ge2$.  What you see in the plot are approximations of the curves $y=\frac{c}{k} x \log^2 x$ for $k=6,12,24,...$, since the mean of a twin pair is a multiple of 6.

Added: Notice the same effect when plotting simply the maximum prime factor of 6n versus n:
[image]

Comment: Your idea enlightens me. But i think The n-th twin prime pair appears to be around f(n), here n=c f(n) /log^2 f(n)

Comment: Correct. I was using $cn\log^2n$ as a quick estimate: I couldn't find a good reference for an easily described approximation to the nth twin primes (my standard references do not have this).  For the $n$ in your plot, the nth twin prime pair is roughly $1.5 n \log^2 n$, and my answer explained what you were seeing.

Comment: $n=cf(n)/\log^2f(n), f(n)=cn\log^2f(n)$.Is it accurate to estimate the n−th twin prime as $cn\log^2n $ ?

Comment: An accurate estimate is not necessary to explain the phenomenon you are observing.  For small $n$, as in your plot, the nth twin prime, for $500\le n \le 10000$, the nth twin prime is certainly between $1.48 n \log^2 n$ and $1.7 n \log^2 n$.  A better estimate appears to be $$f(n)=c n \frac{\log^2 n}{ \log \log n}$$ though I'm still not sure this is the true correct estimate.

Comment: That should be $$f(n)=\frac{cn \log^2 n}{\log \log \log n}$$